# Почему не транслируются значения атрибутов в SOAP запрос

Tags: java, java-ee, soap

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть пример SOAP запроса

```html
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
         <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <SOAP:Body>
         <GetParameter xmlns="http://examples/2001">
   <request>
         <MonCode xmlns="http://newsite/mon">Latency</MonCode>
   <TimeFrom xmlns="http://newsite/mon">2016-10-26T11:00</TimeFrom>
   <TimeTo xmlns="http://newsite/mon">2016-10-26T12:00</TimeTo>
         </request>
   </GetParameter>
         </SOAP:Body>
         </SOAP:Envelope>
```

Формирую SOAP запрос на JAVA, использую SAAJ API

следующий код

```
           MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop/");

    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
    SOAPElement bodyElement = body.addChildElement("GetParameter");
    bodyElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://examples/2001");
    bodyElement = body.addChildElement("request");
    SOAPElement paramsElement = bodyElement.addChildElement("MonCode");
    paramsElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://newsite/mon");
    paramsElement.addTextNode("Latency");
    paramsElement = bodyElement.addChildElement("TimeFrom");
    paramsElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://newsite/mon");
    paramsElement.addTextNode("2016-10-26T11:00");
    paramsElement = bodyElement.addChildElement("TimeTo");
    paramsElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://newsite/mon");
    paramsElement.addTextNode("2016-10-26T12:00");
```

в результате получаю такой SOAP запрос

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <GetParameter xmlns=""/>
    <request>
      <MonCode xmlns="">Latency</MonCode>
      <TimeFrom xmlns="">2016-10-26T11:00</TimeFrom>
      <TimeTo xmlns="">2016-10-26T12:00</TimeTo>
    </request>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Все хорошо, НО куда-то деваются значения атирибутов "http://examples/2001" "http://newsite/mon".

В чем моя ошибка и как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в результате получилось следующее

```
       MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

// Retrieve different parts
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

// Two ways to extract headers
    //    SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
    //    soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();

// Two ways to extract body
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
        soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();

// To add some element

        SOAPElement GetParamter=soapBody.addBodyElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://examples/2001", "GetParamter"));

        GetParamter = GetParamter.addChildElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("request"));
        SOAPElement MonCode=GetParamter.addChildElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://newsite/mon", "MonCode"));
        MonCode.addTextNode("Latency");

        SOAPElement TimeFrom=GetParamter.addChildElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://newsite/mon", "TimeFrom"));
        TimeFrom.addTextNode("2016-10-26T11:00");

        SOAPElement TimeTo=GetParamter.addChildElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://newsite/mon", "TimeTo"));
        TimeTo.addTextNode("2016-10-26T12:00");
```

результирующий SOAP запрос

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<GetParamter xmlns="http://examples/2001">
<request>
<MonCode xmlns="http://newsite/mon">Latency</MonCode>
<TimeFrom xmlns="http://newsite/mon">2016-10-26T11:00</TimeFrom>
<TimeTo xmlns="http://newsite/mon">2016-10-26T12:00</TimeTo>
</request>
</GetParamter>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```